# Unix commands for generating random alphabet

Tags: shell-script

I have to write a script for this program. choose a random letter within `a-z`.  Ask the user to guess the letter, match it with the chosen letter. If matched,  display "correct", else prompt if the guessed letter is above or below the chosen letter. Can someone demonstrate with examples of how I might do this in the shell?

Comment: Shell-script means `KSH`? `(BA)SH`? `(T)CSH`? Builtins only? Standard BSD-userland?

Comment: stack overflow is likely a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @yeti anyone among sh or bash

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you having problems with? We're happy to answer specific questions, but what you're asking for is someone to write a script for you. We're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 6):

## BASH

BASH is nice for this job because BASH can generate the alphabet easily by using `{a..z}` and BASH can input a single char without needing to hit ENTER

```
$ cat guesschar.bash 
c=$(echo {a..z} | tr -d ' ')
x=${c:$((RANDOM%26)):1}
while read -n1 -p'guess the char: ' ; do
        echo
        if [[ $REPLY < $x ]] ; then echo too low...
        elif [[ $REPLY > $x ]] ; then echo too high...
        else break
        fi
done
echo $x ... 'hit!'
$ bash guesschar.bash 
guess the char: m
too high...
guess the char: f
too low...
guess the char: j
too low...
guess the char: k
k ... hit!
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: thanks a lot...i can use the same code in sh also r wat??

Comment: No. In `sh` this will be a much longer program. Compare the documentation. I think `sh` will not have the range expression `{a..z}`, not the RANDOM variable and not reading single keystrokes via `read -n1`.

Comment: No, this wouldn't be a much longer program in plain shell - I'm pretty sure I could do this shorter in shell - but both programs would be ASCII locale specific. If you wanted to do this and handle *any* alphabet... well, *that* would be a much longer program.

Answer (score 2):

```
rand=$(tr -dc '[:lower:]' </dev/urandom | 
    dd bs=1 count=1 status=none)
until [ "$in" = "$rand" ] && echo "correct" ; do
    in=$(stty raw 
    dd bs=1 count=1 status=none </dev/tty 
    stty sane )
    echo
done
```

I think the above does what you need.

Comment: May I suggest `head -c 1` instead of `dd...` for handling ASCII char one by one?. Just a suggestion though, but it's a bit more readable

Comment: @igeorget - good suggestion, but I think just the `echo` handles that. And `dd` is portable - even if `/dev/urandom` probably isn't.

Comment: hmmm... tested replacing occurrences of `dd bs=1 count=1 status=none` by `head -c1`, I got exactly the same behaviour. Well, anyway, that's just a matter of style, nothing important :)

Comment: What behavior? You mean the characters stringing together? That's `stty raw` doing that - that's why I added the `echo`.

Comment: You get my +1 for usage of `/dev/urandom` : shell has many tools for read/write operations and there is a PRNG accessible through the filesystem so no need to generate the random bytes in the code

Comment: No, I meant reading a single character

Comment: @igeorget - amen to that. And besides - I wouldn't think `bash`'s `$random` would be doing much different. But I haven't checked and don't know for sure.

Comment: @igeorget - I just made it a little more efficient. Since I'm using `dd` anyway... Nevermind... I think that broke it. *should have* worked...

Comment: Note that this answer assumes a locale with single-byte charset.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - yeah I already did note that.

Comment: @lgeorget `head -c1` might be doing buffered I/O underneath the covers, which would lead to very unintended behavior if you are using it to trim characters before passing the rest of the input to another tool. `dd` is always calling raw I/O primitives with exactly the values you specify. That's beside the fact that basic `dd` use is portable to basically every UNIX-like system since v7, while the `-c` flag for `head` is still only gradually becoming ubiquitous. If you remain aware of the consequences of that - especially the buffered I/O - when `head -c1` works, it's more readable and obvious.

Comment: Basically, I don't know if every `head` implementation bypasses buffered I/O for `-c`, but I certainly wouldn't count on it without some sort of documented guarantee, because typical `head` implementations *definitely* do buffered I/O when in line mode, so it would be intuitive and reasonable for a coder to just used the same buffered standard I/O functions for `-c` reads too.

Comment: @mtraceur Ah, that's good to know and to keep in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a portable way, you can try:

```
perl -e 'print(("a".."z")[rand 26])'
```